# Should Schema.org be used on embedded YouTube videos or only self-hosted videos?

Tags: google-search, video, schema.org

[Google supports and recommends using the schema.org on-page markup for videos.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2413309?hl=en&topic=1088474&ctx=topic) However it is not clear if this should also be done when embeddeding a YouTube video. Or really even a Vimeo video. Or is the schema.org only necessary when hosting the videos yourself?

Comment: Do you ask if Google might show a Rich Snippet for externally hosted videos, or do you want to know if it’s allowed according to Schema.org?

Comment: Is the Google embed `<iframe>` already setup for Bing/Google to get the data from or do I need to add Schema around it?

Answer (score 1):

schema.org is never *necessary* and you are free to markup (or not) whatever you wish, including third-party content. It's up to you if you wish to add markup or not — there's nothing saying you shouldn't. Feel free to use `sameAs` to refer back to the original youtube.com/etc page.